# Unable to launch the BiodiversityR Graphical User Interface; "hasJava" Error

Tags: java, r

I'm unable to launch the BiodiversityR Graphical User Interface of the BiodiversityR package. When I load the R Commander without BiodiversityR, everthing works fine. I'm also able to load the package "rJava". The 64-bit version of Java is already installed.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Greetings
Tina

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

> library(BiodiversityR)
Lade nötiges Paket: tcltk
Lade nötiges Paket: vegan
Lade nötiges Paket: permute
Lade nötiges Paket: lattice
This is vegan 2.3-0
BiodiversityR 2.5-3: use function 'BiodiversityRGUI()' to launch the BiodiversityR Graphical User Interface

> BiodiversityRGUI()
Eingelesen: BiodiversityGUI.R 
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'Rcmdr', details:
  call: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
  error: could not find function "hasJava"
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Rcmdr'
> system("java -version")
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Rcmdr** package no longer uses Java, and the function `hasJava()`, which was defined in and exported by the **Rcmdr**, no longer exists. Apparently **BioDiversityR** uses this function and needs to be updated appropriately.

You might report your problem directly to the maintainer of **BioDiversityR**.

I hope this help,
 John